# how i can use lollipop features on API 15

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, android-appcompat, android-design-library

I have 2 questions:

1. Is it possible to use the material in API 15?
2. If yes so how can I do this?

I Mean to use android:elevation and more like.

Comment: Please tell your problem statement

Comment: You can use material design for API below 15 using support library

Comment: but I can't use 'android:elevation'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is it possible to use the material in API 15?
>      I Mean to use android:elevation and more lik

It depends.

You can use some wigdets and views, like [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) adding the **AppCompat Support Library** or  [CollapsingToolbarLayout](http://CollapsingToolbarLayout), [SnackBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html), [FloatingActionButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html) adding the new **Design Support Library**.

But there are some features that **can work only with API 21+.**
For example android:elevation (shadows) or [RippleDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable.html) which were introduced with Android 5.0 and not are in the support libraries.

> 2 .If yes so how can I do this?

You can start from:

- adding the [AppCompat support library](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html):
- adding the [Design support library](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)